# Call javascript function from react in txt/javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i have this react component I wanted to use inside a plain html page served by flask

All works fine with my build/development with gulp
But now i wanted to use a specific part in my flask app

So in my `app.js` I have

```
var RenderX = function() {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Example/>, document.getElementById('app')
    );
};

exports = RenderX;
```

Now I want to call this function inside my html page (served by flask)

```
<script src="/static/scripts/vendor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/scripts/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">RenderX();</script>
```

It tells me `RenderX` can not be found
How can i solve this problem I am facing

I want to migrate some part of my code bit by bit to react.

Comment: When you look at the developer tools (F12) does it show that app.js has been imported or is there an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using a module bundler to handle your dependencies. Maybe Browserify or Webpack?

```
exports = RenderX;
```

When the module bundler combines your files to create `scripts/app.js` it wraps each of them in a immediately invoked function expression.

```
// simplified version
(function(module, exports) {
  var RenderX = function() {
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Example/>, document.getElementById('app')
    );
  };

  exports = RenderX;
})();
```

Setting `exports` doesn't expose your function as a global variable, because `exports` is just a value handled by the module bundler.

Instead, declare the function directly on the window object.

```
var RenderX = function() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Example/>, document.getElementById('app')
  );
};

window.RenderX = RenderX;
```

That way you'll be able to call it from outside the scope of your module.

Comment: Thank you very much, i knew I was missing something, but this does the trick